# Excel VBA remove blank row after cut

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code which cuts and pastes an entire row to another sheet, how could I remove the blank row which now appears on the first sheet in which the original row was cut.

```
Set ASR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
Set LS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Exclusions")

ASR.cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=LS.Range("A" & LS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

I was hoping this line of code which I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12986520/excel-vba-remove-blank-rows-in-table) would remove the blank rows, but it did not work

```
ASR.cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Please always specify what doesn't work. Does it not do what you expect? Does it give an error? What is the error message and what line causes the error? Does Excel become unresponsive or crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ASR.cells(i, "C").EntireRow.delete`

Comment: I have this code within a fort loop so now the delete row is distorting the number of rows I am looping through with the for loop, do you know how to adjust for this?

Comment: @phillipsK make sure you are looping backwards through the data set.

Comment: @ScottCraner is there a way to append `Shift:=xlUp` instead?

Comment: save the numbers of the rows to an array, then delete in one go.  You'd need something like `range("a" & I & :"z" & I).delete` to use shift up.  Where z is the last column

Comment: Whenever deleting rows it is best to loop backwards, or keep track of the rows to delete using union and delete them as one.

Comment: @ScottCraner `For i = LR To 2` with LR being the last row, how do I change `next i` into a decrement?

Comment: `For i = LR To 2 Step -1` @phillipsK