# How do I copy values only from one sheet and paste them into a sheet that has a table set up?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy data from a sheet to another sheet. The sheet that is being pasted into has a table created in it and I want to paste the values into the table. I have this code here to do the copy but it doesn't do the copy.

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim s As Long, w As Long

With Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD")
LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2")
w = .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For s = 2 To LastRow1
With Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD")
.Rows(s).Resize(, 6).Copy 'Destination:=Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2 
").Range("A" & w)
    Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").Range("A" & w).PasteSpecial 
Paste:=xlPasteValues

    w = w + 1
    End With
    Next s
```

Comment: (1) "*it doesn't do the copy*" does this mean it does nothing at all? Can you please describe what it actually does instead of the expected behavior? (2) I see you increment `w` but you don't use `w` at all, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: It does nothing at all. and i want the increment of w  to fill down the sheet

Comment: Ok but you don't use `w` at all in your code yet. It's hard to tell without knowing more details. But your `For` loops runs from row 2 to last row in worksheet `PlaceHolderDD` copies it and then pasts every row into the exact same range called `Table1[No.]` so that's your issue I think.

Comment: @takanuva15 You should not be rude and LOL on other users. We have a [be-nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i edited my code above with new one and this seems to work but then on the pasting to sheet it paste blank values from the copy from sheet.

Comment: Ok sorry I'll delete that comment

Comment: the code i have in the updated post works perfectly, however it  extends the table size to include the blank rows from the copy from sheet

Comment: Do your tables start in cell 'A1'? Or are they down lower on the worksheet?

Comment: The table has its headings in A1:F1. starting from row A2 is where the data will be pasted. But the copied data pastes starting on A3

Comment: @takanuva15 I found a solution with the code in the updated post, however the table extend to include blank rows from the copy from sheet. I really appreciate the time.

Comment: Do you want me to help you find a solution that avoids copying blank rows?

Comment: @takanuva15 Yes.

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer with your code and a new If statement to check if the row is blank before it copy pastes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150768/discussion-between-richmond-and-takanuva15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, assuming you have data in all the rows you are copy-pasting over, it seems that you are only pasting into the 1st row of the table. The following fix worked for me in my tests:

UPDATE: Changed code according to OP solution and added extra to ignore blank rows

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim s As Long, w As Long

    With Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD")
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("KYC Feedback Page 2")
        w = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For s = 2 To LastRow1
        Worksheets("PlaceHolderDD").Rows(s).Copy
        Sheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").Range("Table1[No.]").Select
        Selection.Offset(w, 0).Select 'Additional Line here
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        w = w + 1
    Next s

    Dim Rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Sheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").Range("Table1[No.]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you should [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) and use `Sheets("KYC Feedback Page 2").Range("Table1[No.]").Offset(w, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False` instead.

Comment: This one doesn't insert the copied values into the table. it paste them starting on row 3

Comment: I really appreciate you guys' help. the code i have in the updated post works perfectly, however it extends the table size to include the blank rows from the copy from sheet

Comment: it works but it stills hows the blank rows in the table. I am thinking how i can delete blank rows from a table.

Comment: Ok I just added in [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987329/6854489) to delete the blank rows. Try it out now

Comment: I get an error on this line (method 'Range' of object'_worksheet failed): 

     Set Rng = Range("Table1[No.]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

Comment: I think that's because the worksheet wasn't specified. I changed the code again; try it one more time

Comment: I really appreciate your help and will try it again tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Again, I really thank you for your time.